# Mutual Client Authentication Get Certificate in Servlet

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat6

I have setup a Tomcat 7.0 application server with mutual (client/server) authentication over SSL.  To setup this configuration I needed to create a .jks file for the server and .pks certificate for in my web browser.  After configuring the server.xml file in Tomcat I have mutual authentication and SSL working.  Now I am attempting to grab the certificate in a servlet, however I cannot seem to grab the certificate from the request in the servlet.  I can setup a filter that successfully pulls the certificate from the request.  Can anyone provide me with a configuration/code that would allow me to grab the certificate from the servlet?  I would also accept a reason for why I cannot get the certificate in the servlet.

Server.xml

```
<Connector
 clientAuth="true" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
 scheme="https" secure="true"
 keystoreFile="C:/Users/Kevin Bowersox/Desktop/Development/My Certs/server.jks"
 keystoreType="JKS" keystorePass="notmypassword"
 truststoreFile="C:/Users/Kevin Bowersox/Desktop/Development/My Certs/server.jks"
 truststoreType="JKS" truststorePass="notmypassword"
 SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLVerifyDepth="2" sslProtocol="TLS"
/>
```

MyServlet.java - This throws a RuntimeException because certificate is not found when hitting url: https://localhost:8443/Sample_Application/MyServlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
            if (null != certs && certs.length > 0) {
                System.out.println("cert found");
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("No X.509 client certificate found in request");
    }
```

MyServlet Mapping

```
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

MyFilter.java - Returns "cert found" when hitting url: https://localhost:8443/Sample_Application/test.jsp

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
        if (null != certs && certs.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("cert found");
        }
        //throw new RuntimeException("No X.509 client certificate found in request");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

My Filter Mapping

```
<filter>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>MyFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: We need to see the security constraints from the web.xml as well please. Also the SSLVerify* settings on the connector will do nothing - those are the names of httpd configuration settings.

Comment: @Mark Thomas I do not currently have access to my web.xml file, but I know that I do not have any security parameters set in that file.  Do I need to?

Comment: If there are no security constraints defined and the connector is not configured to require a client SSL cert, Tomcat isn't going to ask for one and the client isn't going to provide it.

Comment: @MarkThomas The connector is configured to require a client SSL cert, in fact it works! I go to the site, it prompts me for a cert and I provide it, this part works.  Do I need to specify something in web.xml to get the certificate in a servlet?

Comment: OK. Missed the clientAuth="true" when I looked at your connector config. Are you sure it isn't working? I assume you realise that with the posted code you will always get a RuntimeException regardless of whether or not a certificate is present. Are you sure there is no "cert found" message in the logs? Every released version of Tomcat 7 has passed the Servlet 3.0 TCK and that includes tests for client certificate authentication with a test that the certificate is available to a servlet. No additional configuration is required to expose it. Tomcat automatically populates the request attribute.

Comment: @Mark Thomas You were exactly right I was getting the message printed in the logs.  I was getting it confused with the filter.  Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is working. However, the Servlet is coded to always throws the RuntimeException so it looks like it isn't working.

Comment: Easily done - I have done far worse in my time. And the tomcat commit history is there for all to see :)